# docker container tmp folder full

Tags: docker

I can't npm install because `npm WARN tar ENOSPC: no space left on device, write` inside docker container. I check the space of my `/tmp` folder using `df -h /tmp`. 99% used, I add a remove tmp folder command but doesn't work.

**Inside container**

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  24.1G     23.9G    181.2M  99% /
```

**/var/lib/docker Usages df-h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M   22M  179M  11% /run
/dev/vda1        49G  6.8G   42G  14% /
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/0
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/6e1df9a8f52cb302f46272340fa647c14d60a0bfc261f3e9629ffede92de5898/merged
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/dcc995f1e015688463de51704f35874683a29a1f2e2478bc9192ec8fd53042e9/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/d72785d20ee62d6db718be7644197d60ce7e4cdf1341eb7945a25a37b21f9172/mounts/shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/7b3b892baa4a85bd04e7aa23b0f1d561d483ea6010f96dbd52a6af727582a063/mounts/shm
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/bf7a4c992a584065b37c5d2598ec6339a98c16c7aba22e405ec1d404e1da8e6d/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/6356136081e544631fc97471754a119c9b769162f73314287c4cbb20e1ce8d62/mounts/shm
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/f905b2e51f815a7d2385e2eafcbbecca7881ba7fbffbf829927164c2c088dc00/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/991b04b7ff7a6532ba4b82d443022bea0cefa3d37c82c780bae6a7ad51914ed8/mounts/shm
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/7682c5490149bdca59c5b8a2118fe11e4e9cdf8d0c175e86784483ffdf3351c7/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/00074204f86855f224d7058041e0785546daf9d3e09cb4f44b95661c3e4469e4/mounts/shm
overlay          49G  6.8G   42G  14% /home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/mounts/shm
```

**/var/lib/docker Usages df-ih**

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             248K   384  248K    1% /dev
tmpfs            251K   697  250K    1% /run
/dev/vda1        6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /
tmpfs            251K     1  251K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            251K     6  251K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            251K    16  250K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15          0     0     0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            251K     4  251K    1% /run/user/0
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/6e1df9a8f52cb302f46272340fa647c14d60a0bfc261f3e9629ffede92de5898/merged
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/dcc995f1e015688463de51704f35874683a29a1f2e2478bc9192ec8fd53042e9/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/d72785d20ee62d6db718be7644197d60ce7e4cdf1341eb7945a25a37b21f9172/mounts/shm
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/7b3b892baa4a85bd04e7aa23b0f1d561d483ea6010f96dbd52a6af727582a063/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/bf7a4c992a584065b37c5d2598ec6339a98c16c7aba22e405ec1d404e1da8e6d/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/6356136081e544631fc97471754a119c9b769162f73314287c4cbb20e1ce8d62/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/f905b2e51f815a7d2385e2eafcbbecca7881ba7fbffbf829927164c2c088dc00/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/991b04b7ff7a6532ba4b82d443022bea0cefa3d37c82c780bae6a7ad51914ed8/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/7682c5490149bdca59c5b8a2118fe11e4e9cdf8d0c175e86784483ffdf3351c7/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/00074204f86855f224d7058041e0785546daf9d3e09cb4f44b95661c3e4469e4/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/e7bad84d978976233216308e10fc600c1b7956d8991060f792871823d0350cba/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/71f23bf09ce2bf44ca76b568850308a655f5b5e981a1c4dc4820e03e7edee773/mounts/shm
overlay          6.2M  345K  5.9M    6% /home/docker/overlay2/920f3dc9f832dcde427a827737b8aab355b6839c59cef8e592b31dcba1e4be61/merged
shm              251K     1  251K    1% /home/docker/containers/b422e8cabf6112ce860ed924f820ed1940273d93e96a37b4ea775d74540a2cb1/mounts/shm
```

**Docker Info**

```
Containers: 8
 Running: 8
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 7
Server Version: 18.09.3
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: e6b3f5632f50dbc4e9cb6288d911bf4f5e95b18e
runc version: 6635b4f0c6af3810594d2770f662f34ddc15b40d
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-143-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.953GiB
Name: {Server-name}
ID: 3ST7:BBF2:SARX:YZP6:ZREZ:Z7BK:5IYV:AJ6Z:2NTG:3F2R:EYKP:ETWK
Docker Root Dir: /home/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

**Docker Inspect**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3",
        "Created": "2019-04-09T03:25:48.571426107Z",
        "Path": "npm",
        "Args": [
            "start"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 473,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-04-09T03:25:49.493986988Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:6bfd6eba3a8c669caa7531592c5b01d6d1f24f6de30d3f0f6133ab932f9fa1b4",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/home/docker/containers/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3/e0e75a420e3126645734ea55bddeccff8c5b4c95fcaaa326b96a765dee88f8b3-json.log",
        "Name": "/appServer",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "traefik_proxy",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8889/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8889"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60-init/diff:/home/docker/overlay2/a50a2534da040e431c25cc08ed28dd8488d40b291db975e8c03aa56e7c523ccc/diff:/home/docker/overlay2/025c625fedfabedfb9217a15aa71e2e6ae221915d2bbcf9c77c2c94d8e799ba9/diff:/home/docker/overlay2/84844b839da1e829877a26b9a5921e6fe2bc118cc27348b64bb0b8d02462e8cc/diff:/home/docker/overlay2/4ff909483d30be4c779579516d8dff39f8123e7e6114871f71cc7eaa69b953b1/diff:/home/docker/overlay2/fb7de39793554b2fbfa00b48e7851c5b003e2d40ef26fa959f2ba6ab27ac9421/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/home/docker/overlay2/22376e843826d4be505868904dbd0dcc477b4997a96cc2debd40ac2073049c60/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "e0e75a420e31",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8889/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "NODE_ENV=production",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=10.15.3",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.13.0"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "npm",
                "start"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "cloud.canister.io:5000/randomUser/appServer:94ed04b",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "traefik.backend": "appServer",
                "traefik.docker.network": "traefik_proxy",
                "traefik.enable": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost": "website.com",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds": "315360000",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny": "true",
                "traefik.frontend.rule": "Host:website.com",
                "traefik.port": "8889"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "00510757a3eb7cd8ca00c41169a72cae55c46b7608a71961062356cf81840a2a",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8889/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8889"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/00510757a3eb",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "traefik_proxy": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "e0e75a420e31"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "950d61fcc027e81f4681236726300b3e178af808e4e49260a967971f67af9518",
                    "EndpointID": "7093732ece6ceab22f18810812a1e6eefc9fb22d244a4c88cdb78edd34f5e8ab",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How to remove `/tmp` inside container? Is it safe to clear overlay folder in docker?

Comment: Which container is that? Is it custom container? If so, could you show us your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir I used drone pipeline commands. `rm -rf /tmp/*` in node:alpine image. For container, I used `docker container run -d ...`

Comment: Could you check your local system's filesystem usage?

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir ^/var/lib/docker usages. I tried to remove the overlay folders after stop docker. It still reserved much space after I pull the images and run container again.

Comment: execute `df -ih` to check for available inode space and make sure you have enough space left to perform read/write.

Comment: @Thilak What if not enough, can I clear ? I can't npm install. No space left on device.

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/docker-container-out-of-space/). Almost looks like your issue.

Comment: I might do some routine debugging (how exactly did your container manage to get that big?) but then just `docker stop && docker rm && docker run` it again with a clean filesystem.

Comment: @DavidMaze each deploy, drone CI will `docker pull && docker container stop && docker container rm && docker container run`

Comment: The container and host `df` output are not lining up. Please include the output of `docker inspect` on the container, `docker info`, and `echo $DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: @BMitch $DOCKER_HOST is empty

Comment: What's not adding up is the container shows 24.1G while the host shows the filesystem should be 49G in size. I'm not seeing anything like device mapper, a different docker host, etc, that would explain the difference. Looks like the container is running on a different host.